# TCP Communication: Send Response

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm new to to socket programming and TCP communication and I'm working on an application that should receive requests (website urls) from a computer that has access to a server but no internet connection, then it should send the website to the client as a response. So far I have been able to listen to requests successfully but when I try to send the response the browsers hangs.

```
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 500);
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                Socket client = listener.AcceptSocket();
                Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted.");
                var childSocketThread = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[100];
                    int size = client.Receive(data);
                    Console.WriteLine("Recieved data: ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(data[i]));
                    // Reading the website in bytes using WebCLient
                    client.Send(RESPONSE) // Here I call the send
                    client.Close();
                });
                childSocketThread.Start();
            }

            listener.Stop();
```

What exactly am I doing wrong and how can I fix this (send responses back to the client) ?

Comment: what do you mean by HANG ? and why you use threads to send response ? is there any specific reason

Comment: @KcDoD: well I'm at hello world level in this subject so if you know something please share with me I wanna learn about that.

Comment: Okay I feel like what you want is a thread join (may be) .. try putting childSocketThread.Join() after start of the thread . Also use console writelines before AcceptSocket to verify code reach there,, Do and tell the updates :)

Comment: What is `RESPONSE`? And where's the logic to make sure it's an appropriate response to the particular query you got? And why in the world would you choose one of the most complex things in existence (an HTTP proxy) as your first foray into socket programming?! Start by reading [the standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.3) and studying carefully every mention of a proxy in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to write an HTTP proxy, you must follow every requirement for proxies in the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html). For example:

> The proxy server MUST signal persistent connections separately with its clients and the origin servers (or other proxy servers) that it connects to. Each persistent connection applies to only one transport link.

and:

> A proxy server MUST NOT establish a HTTP/1.1 persistent connection with an HTTP/1.0 client (but see RFC 2068 [33] for information and discussion of the problems with the Keep-Alive header implemented by many HTTP/1.0 clients).

and:

> - If a proxy receives a request that includes an Expect request-
>         header field with the "100-continue" expectation, and the proxy
>         either knows that the next-hop server complies with HTTP/1.1 or
>         higher, or does not know the HTTP version of the next-hop
>         server, it MUST forward the request, including the Expect header
>         field.
> - If the proxy knows that the version of the next-hop server is
>         HTTP/1.0 or lower, it MUST NOT forward the request, and it MUST
>         respond with a 417 (Expectation Failed) status.
> - Proxies SHOULD maintain a cache recording the HTTP version
>         numbers received from recently-referenced next-hop servers.
> - A proxy MUST NOT forward a 100 (Continue) response if the
>         request message was received from an HTTP/1.0 (or earlier)
>         client and did not include an Expect request-header field with
>         the "100-continue" expectation. This requirement overrides the
>         general rule for forwarding of 1xx responses (see section 10.1).

An HTTP proxy is an incredibly complex beast and possibly the worst possible choice for someone who isn't experienced in writing networking code.

Comment: Your answer is simply perfect David and by taking what you said into the play I've managed to finally implement what I was after. Thank you.